# Get Order and Customer Data of Guest user after `sales_order_place_after` triggered Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order

I need only 
`customer_id, product_id, customer_email`

I am using

```
  <sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
      <checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>amxnotif/observer</class>
        <method>getAlertFrontend</method>
      </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_place_after>
```

In Observer.php

```
public function getAlertFrontend(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
           Mage::log('we are in cataloginventory frontend log start ');
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();  // working

        $customer = $order->getCustomer();
        $productId = $order->getProductId();  
        $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
        $orderItem = $order->getItem();


        Mage::log("order_data start");
        Mage::log( $order->getEmail() );
        Mage::log( $orderItem );
        Mage::log( $customer_id );
        Mage::log("order_data ends");
        $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
        $customerName = $customerData->getName();

         Mage::log("customer_data start");
        Mage::log( $customerName );
        Mage::log( $customerData );

        Mage::log("customer_data ends");


        Mage::log(sprintf('Order Id :: %s ,Product Id :: %s Customer Id :: %s ',$orderId, $productId, $customer_id));

           Mage::log('we are in cataloginventory frontend log ends ');

}
```

But i am only getting `DEBUG (7): Order Id:: 100000144, Product Id::  Customer Id::`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get all order item , you should use `$order->getAllItems()`.

```
$customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();

if(!$order->getCustomerIsGuest()){
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
}
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $order) {
      $items=array();
      foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[] = array(
            'product_id'            => $item->getProductId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),


        );}
```

Comment: how to get  customer_id, product_id, customer_email,

Comment: can you suggest how to get getNotifyStockQty() using above available objects